# I need to get the first log in database java

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example of my database

```
Chin    2015-01-02    9:00
Chris   2015-01-02    9:02
Chin    2015-01-02    10:00
Chris   2015-01-02    9:09
Chin    2015-01-03    8:00
Chin    2015-01-03    9:00
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01
Chris   2015-01-03    9:03
```

so basically, I need a query that can return only the first log-in in the day.
the return value should be:

```
Chin    2015-01-02    9:00
Chris   2015-01-02    9:02
Chin    2015-01-03    8:00
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01
```

PS. I'm using java netbeans

If you can give me a query that can help me get the exact return value i need, thank you!

Comment: What's the data type of that third column?

Comment: I'm using time as a data type

Comment: In that case, my answer will be fine.  I was worried you were going to have to split open a string, which would make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the datatype of the third column, the SQL you want would be something like

```
SELECT name, loginDate, MIN( loginTime )
FROM   logins
GROUP BY name, loginDate
```

But if the third column is just a character type, you'll need to manipulate it first to turn it into a time or a number of minutes.

Comment: okay thank you very much! I just need to refresh my memory because I forgot using SQL. It worked thank you again!